# PowerBi Order categorical slicer by numerical value in same table

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I have a slicer like this: [image: slicer]

And my data has this format:
[image: data format]
And I want these values to appear in the order of the weekdayNumber, but my "Sorting by Columns" is keeping itself gray.

These are the filters I used in the slicer:

[image: filters]

Answer (score 0):

The Power BI Desktop UI is quite glitchy at the moment, and I have seen that behavior a few times.  Try switching to other windows and back, or selecting other fields and returning to select the Weekday field before trying the Sort By Column button again.